# Filter df by date using pyspark

Tags: pyspark

everyone!!
I have tried to filter a dataset in pyspark. I had to filter the column date (date type) and I have written this code, but there is somwthing wrong: the dataset is empty. Someone could tell me how to fix it?

```
df = df.filter((F.col("date") > "2018-12-12") & (F.col("date") < "2019-12-12"))
```

Tanks

Comment: if you filter only on the first condition, does the `df` return results?
what are the `min` and `max` dates in the dataset?

Comment: seems like you overwrite your df by the same df so firstly don't do it. assign the result to a different variable.
Secondly, show us the top 10 rows, let's feel the data.

Comment: Please share your input and output datasets!!

Answer (score 1):

You need first to make sure `date` column is in date format then use `lit` for your filter:

df exemple:

```
df  = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
('20/12/2018', '1', 50),
('18/01/2021', '2', 23),
('31/01/2022', '3', -10)
  ], ['date', 'id', 'value']
)

df.show()

+----------+---+-----+
|      date| id|value|
+----------+---+-----+
|20/12/2018|  1|   50|
|18/01/2021|  2|   23|
|31/01/2022|  3|  -10|
+----------+---+-----+
```

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


df\
    .withColumn('date', F.to_date('date', 'd/M/y'))\
    .filter((F.col('date') > F.lit('2018-12-12')) & (F.col("date") < F.lit('2019-12-12')))\
    .show()

+----------+---+-----+
|      date| id|value|
+----------+---+-----+
|2018-12-20|  1|   50|
+----------+---+-----+
```